# HTACCESS Rule Issue

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I'm trying to redirect URLs like this:

http://www.website.com/blog/portfolio/new-home

to

http://www.website.com/portfolio/new-home

I'm trying to remove the /blog from any URL which contains /blog/portfolio/.

So far I'm trying...

```
RewriteRule ^/blog/portfolio/(.*)$ http://website.com/portfolio/$1 [R=301,L]
```

but it doesn't appear to be working.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this rule as first rule in your main WP .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^blog/(portfolio/.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L,NC,NE]
```

Your rule has a leading slash that is not matched as `.htaccess` is per directory directive and Apache strips the current directory path (thus leading slash) from `RewriteRule` URI pattern.